# jquery : How to use the .css() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html/javascript stuff

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
    $("body").append("Entering function...");
    var element = event.target;
    var color = element.css("background-color");
    $("body").append("That div is <span style='color:" + color + ";'>" + color + "</span>.");
});
</script>

<body>
<div style="background-color:#ff1111;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
<div style="background-color:#223388;width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When running in firebug with a breakpoint at "var color = element.css("background-color");" it tells me that css is undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why is `element` is a DOM element and not a jQuery object.  To use the `css` function you need a jQuery object.

```
var color = $(element).css('background-color');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
 var color = $(element).css("background-color");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `var element = $(event.target)` instead. The `css` method is a jQuery method

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
var element = $(event.target);
```

Answer (score 0):

**To add more in line styling this code will help a lot**

```
var color = $(element).css({'color':'red','background-color':'blue'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of "event" as parameter shrouds the meaning of the global `event` object.

Use `e` or any other valid variable name in your callback method.

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
...

    var color = $(e.target).css("background-color");
    alert("Color is " + color);
});
```